# subscribe(new Subscriber<XXX>() ...) on Observer object is not working Retrofit-RxJava

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm following this tutorial https://youtu.be/YoSr5mi5kKU?t=30m52s to learn a bit on RxJava and MVP pattern in Android.

But when it arrives the momento to observe the object this now works:

```
public void getDataTMDBinteractor() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("api_key", "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
    Observable<ResponseTMDB> responseTMDBObservable = serviceTMDB.getDataTMBDService(params);

    responseTMDBObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseTMDB>() { //Starting error from here
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ResponseTMDB responseTMDB) {

            }
        });
}
```

[image]

The error is: Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous rx.Subscriber)'

And the Service Interface is like this:

```
public interface ServiceTMDB {
    @GET("movie/popular")
    Observable<ResponseTMDB> getDataTMBDService(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
}
```

I don't know what exactly I'm missing or doing bad.

Gradle imports:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Comment: P.D: I'm looking for others examples of RxAndroid/RxJAva, and all do the same, for example: http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple problem, you are adding

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

which works with RxJava 1.x

---

But for

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

you should be adding

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

Comment: i'm adding wgat you said, and I'm getting this errror: Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.1.0. At this moment looks like: `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.1.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'`

Comment: Gah, you're right, it claimed to be updated but it's stuck on RC4! I added a different dependency, you'll need to use `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())` for it to work.

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2 will exist after Retrofit 2.2.0 release

Answer (score 0):

You are adding:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```